# How to get the coordinates of my position?

Tags: x-rebirth

I've been using Roguey's map to track things down in X Rebirth, but I have no idea how to obtain the coordinates of the current location of the Albion Skunk. I've done quite a bit of Googling on the matter, but the game is either too new, or the answer is extremely obvious and I just missed it like a fool. Thanks very much for all answers provided.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure exactly if this is what you need, but we have a mod that exports
the current position in the log file: https://github.com/timothyparez/xrebirth-playerposition

We're going to use this to create a 'second screen' experience where your tablet 
can represent a map.
The source code may help you to get an idea how to get the current position.

Comment: Was there any success with 'second screen' experience?

Comment: Hi, sadly no. The game turned out to be such a mess that it was no longer fun playing it. My friends and I have long since moved on to Elite Dangerous.

Comment: Quote from "Patola", who posted it as an answer: "The mod does not work; it does not output the position. Also, the variable it uses - player.primaryship.position - only output the zone coordinates (just as in the screenshot info), which is useless for roguey's site, which uses sector coordinates."

Comment: Hi, I haven't looked at that in years sorry. I gave op on rebirth and moved to Elite Dangerous. I tried rebirth again a few months ago but I just can't get myself invested anymore.

Comment: I can tell you though @Patola that back in the day the code did in fact work, but so much has changed since then. It's probably no longer compatible.

Answer (score 3):

When you press <kbd>PrntScr</kbd> game makes screenshot. In screenshot folder for each image there are text files with same name, that contain position of player ship like this:

```
<teleport zone="tzonecluster_d_sector18_zone50_macro">
<offset>
<position x="-2890.886" y="1270.002" z="-865.186"/>
<rotation yaw="-8.44914" pitch="2.40675" roll="-175.97554"/>
</offset>
</teleport>
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this is very old, but I've gotten the position in km as follows:

```
%,.0skm %,.0skm %,.0skm'.[player.zone.position.x/1000,player.zone.position.y/1000,player.zone.position.z/1000]
```